# can you express universal quantification ∀x(Px ≡ Qx) simply as Px ≡ Qx?

Tags: symbolic-logic

Is it permissible and normal to express the prop. `∀x(Px ≡ Qx)` simply as `Px ≡ Qx`? That is, to treat the univ. quantifier as implicit if its scope is all the rest of the prop.?

Comment: As a complement to the accepted answer below: the first proposition can be translated "all Ps are Qs and conversely" and the second "if it's a P, it's a Q and conversely" where the reference of "it" is unspecified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer depends a bit on context,

generally no, you cannot express ∀x(Px ≡ Qx) as simply Px ≡ Qx . The reason has to do with bound and unbound variables. (http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs381/cs381content/logic/pred_logic/quantification/quantification.html)

Thus, seeing x without the ∀ means something different than (∀x) precisely because x in the former would represent a specific x whereas in the latter use it does not refer to a specific thing but rather is a variable standing over a range .